# Expressing D[1/D1, x] in terms of D1 when D1 = 1 + x

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, replacement

For simplicity, taking `D1` to be equal to `1 + x`, I want to evaluate the derivative of `1/D1` (which is `-1/(1 + x)^2`) and express it in terms of `D1` (as `-1/D1^2`). For further calculations, I want to keep `D1` in all the expressions.

```
D1 = 1 + x;
D[1/D1, x]/.(1 + x) -> D1
```

does not work. Can someone help me.

Answer (score 4):

```
D1 = 1 + x;
D[1/D1, x] /. (1 + x) -> HoldForm@D1
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But you need to release the hold to use the result later (if you need to do any calculations with it). If not, you can keep the hold on.  Reason it did not work before, because Mathematica will evaluate `D1` back to `1+x`.

Answer (score 4):

If you already know that later on you want to work with `D1` as an abstract symbol again, it's usually a hint not to introduce general substitution rules into the pattern matcher that will always fire, like `D1 = something`.

Instead you can fire the substitution manually exactly when you want with `/.` / `Replace`. So in your example you could achieve the same with

```
d1tox = D1 -> x + 1;
xtod1 = x -> D1 - 1;
D[1/D1 /. d1tox, x] /. xtod1
```

> $-\frac{1}{\text{D1}^2}$

with full control over substitution and without polluting the global pattern matcher with rules for `D1`.

Answer (score 3):

```
D1 = 1 + x;

D[1/D1, x] /. (1 + x) -> Defer[D1]
```

> -1/D1^2

Same story as @Nasser's answer except that `Defer` is a bit more automated than `HoldForm`: for `Defer`, the hold is released automatically when you use an output as a new input.

To be a bit more general, maybe substitute `x -> Defer[D1] - 1` instead of what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
constraint = x + 1 - D1 == 0;
Simplify[Dt[1/D1]/Dt[x], constraint && Dt[constraint]]
(*  -(1/D1^2)  *)
```

Works with constraints where `D[D1, x]` is not trivial (`1`):

```
constraint = 2 x + 1 - D1 == 0;
Simplify[Dt[1/D1]/Dt[x], constraint && Dt[constraint]]
(*  -(2/D1^2)  *)
```

`Simplify` is not robust since it tries to find the simplest expression, which is not always the same thing as eliminating `x`.  `Eliminate[]` is more appropriate, but it works only on equations, which makes it inconvenient, too.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `D1[x]` instead of `D1` you can just use a derivative subvalue::

```
D1 /: Derivative[1][D1] = 1&;
```

Then:

```
D[1/D1[x],x]
```

> -(1/D1[x]^2)

Another possibility is to make use of the [`NonConstants`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonConstants) option of [`D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/D):

```
SetOptions[D, NonConstants->{D1}];
D1 /: D[D1, x, OptionsPattern[]] = 1;
```

Then:

```
D[1/D1, x]
```

> -(1/D1^2)